# asp.net The resource cannot be found.

Tags: asp.net

I created a simple .net app to test out error 404 (page not found). I have the config file as follows.

```
   <httpErrors>
      <path="/PageNotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   </httpErrors>
```

The PageNotFound.aspx exists. So when I entered a fictitious page name, such as default4.aspx, since it does not exist, I expect it to redirect the request to PageNotFound.aspx, but it doesn't.
I've set the default page to default.aspx, which exist. Once it's launched, I then change the web page at the address bar to default4.aspx. I'm getting the error message below.

The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /TestWebApp/Default4.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

Any Ideas, would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need to define the error code of 404?

Comment: I tried this <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/PageNotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors> but no luck.

Comment: Which version of IIS is it ? Seems 7

Comment: IIS 7.0 on Windows 8.1